# Javascript if else repetition

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'm new to Javascript so please don't judge me... I have a code and I want to avoid repetition of the code, is there a way to do it otherwise?

```
if (dir_x > 0) {
    x++;
    if (dir_y > 0) {
        y++;
    } else {
        y--;
    }
} else {
    x--;
    if (dir_y > 0) {
        y++;
    } else {
        y--;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just remove that block from the condition. `if( dir_x > 0) x++; else x--; if( dir_y > 0) y++; else y--;`

Answer (score 2):

```
if (dir_x > 0) {
    x++;
} else {
    x--;
}
if (dir_y > 0) {
    y++;
} else {
    y--;
}
```

Just place the `y` block outside, since it is not dependant of the `dir_x`

Answer (score 2):

This will basically do the same thing with [Conditional (ternary) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator):

```js
(dir_x > 0) ? x++ : x--;
(dir_y > 0) ? y++ : y--;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add either the result of check or take a negative value wiout using a ternary which result is void.

```
x += dir_x > 0 || -1;
y += dir_y > 0 || -1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviusly there are several ways to do this.
Personally, I would use the following as it makes it instantly clear that some variable's value is being changed.

```
x += dir_x > 0 ? 1 : -1;
y += dir_y > 0 ? 1 : -1;
```

See [Ternary Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) and [Addition Assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Addition_assignment) for details.

Answer (score -2):

If `dir_x` holds value `1` to go right and `-1` to go left and same for `dir_y` then you can simply write:

```
x += dir_x;
y += dir_y;
```